# Force converting to ANSI

Tags: encoding, utf-8, sqlcmd, ansi

I am trying to export a `txt` file in `ANSI` using this command:

```
sqlcmd -S %1 -d %2 -U %3 -P %4  -h-1 -W -f 1252 -i .\filename.sql -o %5\filename.txt
```

But when I open Notepad+ the encoding is still `UTF-8`.

Any idea how to have the file exported in ANSI encoding?

Comment: This is technical question not grammer question. where is the answer in the comments.

Comment: Why do you assume that Notepad+ knows the right encoding? UTF-8 is a good heuristic value, especially if you do not have many non ASCII characters (and often the heuristic is done only on the first part of a file).

Comment: So do not trust notepad+. Do a conclusive test with some special character, and check the encoding, by looking the byte in that file.